# Detect if a StreamingContext is idle with PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

StreamingContext function provides the methods `awaitTermination(timeout=None)` and `awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout)` which both require an external process to stop the context.

Is there any mechanism that can be applied to a StreamingContext job that allows to terminate itself after been idle for some timeout? I mean no data coming from the streaming source for that timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  keep track of the state and execute `ssc.stop()` when specific conditions are satisfied but it is not exactly a pretty solution:

```py
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

def counter(ssc, n=10):
    cnt = {"cnt": 0}
    def _counter(rdd):
        if rdd.isEmpty():
            cnt["cnt"] += 1
        else:
            cnt["cnt"] = 0
        if cnt["cnt"] >= n:
            ssc.stop()
    return _counter

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
cnt = counter(ssc, 5)

stream = ...  # Some DStream
stream.foreachRDD(cnt)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I did come up with a similar approach. The problem is that this is checking if last computation returned some values, not if data was available to last computable RDD. We should ensure that RDDs always return something. Anyway, this is perhaps the best approach achievable at the moment. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: With `take` it shouldn't be a problem but you can always use `isEmpty` for checks.